# How can I find Flea Markets in the USA with more than 1,000 vendors?

Tags: usa, shopping

There are some very large flea markets in the US, but they tend to be in small towns, and the plethora of small ones make it difficult to search for the large ones.

I want to plan a trip visiting some of the large ones.

I am looking for a listing of flea markets that are destination events.  I know about these two.

- [Brimfield Flea Markets, Brimfield MA](https://brimfieldantiquefleamarket.com/)  ~ Not sure of actual vendor count, but it's a couple thousand at least.
- [Rodgers Ohio](http://rogersohio.com/) ~1,600 Vendor spots attendance varies

While [The Elephant Trunk](http://www.etflea.com/) is popular it maxes at about 500 vendors and is not in the scope of this question.

**Edit updating parameters for the question**

Not every state, has a flea market with 1,000+ vendor spaces.  Additionally on researching I am finding several indoor markets advertising themselves as "flea markets" while those have value for the local, they are not destination events.

Looking for the largest outdoor flea markets in each state.  Vendor spaces are rented for the day or the weekend. You park in a single place and walk between the vendors as opposed to a highway yard sale like the [690 mile 127 yard sale](http://www.127yardsale.com/)

Comment: One could just Google something like "list of largest flea markets in the united states" and come up with some nice lists. I suspect, though, that you really want something different from this? BTW, [First Monday Trade Days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Monday_Trade_Days) claims to be the largest in the US, with space for 6000 vendors. They say the hotels in the area are usually booked a year in advance.

Comment: How do you plan to get through 1600 vendors in one day? If doors are open for 8 hours and you take just an hour off-task for meals and running things to the car, that is 420 minutes or 15 seconds per booth *average*. If you spend 2/3 of your time in extended study of booths of interest, that leaves 5 seconds to size up a booth. You can't even walk between them that fast in crowds.

Comment: @Harper The OP doesn't say he's going for one day per flea market. The biggest ones will usually run for a few days at least.

Comment: @MichaelHampton when you google as suggested, all to often the top find is antique to shop in strip mall. It actually not as easy as you might think.  The new and smaller places are working harder to get attention, so they are easier to find on google.  The older and larger have lots of traffic and all the locals know about them, so they have smaller internet foot prints.

Comment: You know that there is more than one search result, right?

Comment: @MichaelHampton [there 5.6 million search results](https://www.google.com/search?q="list+of+largest+flea+markets+in+the+united+states&rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS817US817&oq="list+of+largest+flea+markets+in+the+united+states) you know they are not all the largest right? As stated in the question, the challenge is in finding the largest, and weeding out the small but popular, and the tiny but large advertising budget.

Answer (score 2):

This is a community wiki work in progress. Listing by State, outdoor flea markets with over 1,000 vendors *OR* one of three largest in the state.

### Alabama

### Alaska

### Arizona

### Arkansas

### California

[Alameda Point Antiques Fair](https://alamedapointantiquesfaire.com/) claims over 800 vendor booths, and runs monthly.

### Colorado

### Connecticut

- [The Elephant Trunk](http://www.etflea.com/) ~500 vendor sites

### Delaware

- [Laurel Junction.](https://laureljunction.com/) 25 acre Indoor/Outdoor (*vendor site count not listed, <250 per photos*)

### Florida

- [Waldo Farmers and Flea Market](http://waldofleamarket.com) ~900 Vendor spaces
- [Wagon Wheel Flea Market](http://thewagonwheelfleamarket.com/) Claiming 2,000 vendors, looks like 300+ outside

### Georgia

- [Smileys Georga](https://smileysfleamarkets.com/georgia/) Claims ~1,000 space Google, looks like about 300 outside spaces
- [Keller Flea Market](https://ilovefleas.com/) Google looks like about 250 outside spaces

### Hawaii

### Idaho

### Illinois

### Indiana

### Iowa

### Kansas

### Kentucky

### Louisiana

### Maine

- [Montsweag Flea Market](https://www.montsweagfleamarket.org/) Billed as the largest in the area, (~150 tables from Google views)

### Maryland

- [Brumwells Flea Market](http://www.brumwellflea.com/) 300+ Vendor spaces

### Massachusetts

- [Brimfield Flea Markets, Brimfield MA](https://brimfieldantiquefleamarket.com/)  ~ Not sure of actual vendor count, but it's a couple thousand at least.

### Michigan

### Minnesota

### Mississippi

### Missouri

### Montana

### Nebraska

### Nevada

### New Hampshire

- [Hollis Flea Market](http://www.hollisflea.com/) ~400 Vendor spaces

### New Jersey

- [Berlin Farmer's Market](https://www.berlinfarmersmarket.com/) ~700 Vendor spaces
- [Route 70 Flea Market](https://www.rt70fleamarket.com) ~ 600 Vendor space
- [Collingwood Auction, Flea Market and Farmers Market](http://www.collingwoodfleamarket.com/index.php) ~500 Vendor spaces

### New Mexico

### New York

- [Stormville Airport Antique Show & Flea Market](https://www.stormvilleairportfleamarket.com/) ~600 Vendor spaces

### North Carolina

- [Smiley’s Flea Market in Fletcher, North Carolina](https://smileysfleamarkets.com/north-carolina/) billed as the largest has 600 vendor tables.

### North Dakota

### Ohio

- [Rodgers Ohio](http://rogersohio.com/) ~1,600 Vendor spots attendance varies

### Oklahoma

### Oregon

### Pennsylvania

- *Found 2 the listed ~300 outdoor spaces, and 2 that don't say but look like around 300 outdoor spaces)
- [Blue Ridge Flea Market](http://blueridgefleamarket.com/) Reports ~300 outdoor spaces
- [Renninger's in Adamstown](https://renningers.net/index.php/main-locations/adamstown/adamstown-home) Reports ~300 outdoor spaces
- [Jake's Flea Market](https://www.jakesfleamarket.com/) Google shows about 300 spaces
- [Leighty's Outdoor Flea Market](https://www.leightys.com/fleamarket.htm) Google shows about 300 spaces

### Rhode Island

- [Plainfield Pike Flea Market](https://www.pikefleamarket.com/) 500+ Vendor sites

### South Carolina

- [Florence Flea Market](https://www.facebook.com/florencefleamarket/) 1,000 vendor sites.

### South Dakota

### Tennessee

- [Great Smokies Flea Market](https://greatsmokiesfleamarket.com/) 1,000+ Vendors
- [Nashville Flea Market](http://www.thefairgrounds.com/fleamarket/) 800 to 1200 vendors
- [Tri Cities Flea Market](http://www.tri-citiesfleamarket.com/)1,000+ Vendors

### Texas

- [First Monday Trade Days (Canton, E of Dallas)](http://www.shopfirstmondaycanton.com) 100+ acres, claims to be the oldest and largest in the country, with "space for 6000 vendors"
- [Traders Village (Grand Prairie, between DFW)](https://tradersvillage.com/grand-prairie/directions/) 160 acres, "thousands of shops"
- [Traders Village (Jersey Village, NW of Houston)](https://tradersvillage.com/houston/directions/) 100+ acres, "thousands of dealers"
- [Traders Village (SW of San Antonio)](https://tradersvillage.com/san-antonio/directions/) "over 1,000 vendors"

### Utah

### Vermont

- [Waterbury Flea Market](https://www.waterburyvtfleamarket.com/) 128 vendor spaces billed as largest in the state.

### Virginia

- [Hillsville Memorial & Labor day weekends, VFW](https://groverkingvfw.com/flea-market) & [City](http://www.hillsville.com/fmarket.htm) Vendor count not found, but looks like 1,000+ with 500K in visitors claimed
- [Shen-Valley flea Market](http://doubletollgate.com/aboutus.htm) ~300 Vendor spaces
- [Virginia Bazaar](http://www.vabazaar.com/) ~200 outdoor space

### Washington

### West Virginia

- [West Virginia State Fair, Flea Market & Antique Show](http://statefairofwv.com/event-center/flea-market/) 200+ indoor & outdoor vendors
- [Elkins  Flea Market](http://elkinsfleamarket.com/) 180 Tables

### Wisconsin

- [Elkhorn Antique Flea Market](https://www.nlpromotionsllc.com/#new-page) ~500 vendors indoor & outdoor

### Wyoming

Comment: I added some in Texas. I'm not sure how useful "largest in each state" will be, considering that the ones I added form a triangle that is 200-300 miles per side, which probably covers all of the flea markets in VT, NH, MA, CT, RI, and part of NY.